Matching a pattern and a contiguous character but not the character by itself
I want to use regex in python to match a specified character(s) 0 or more times contiguous with a pattern.
Eg. matching a word with ' potentially present before, in the middle, or at the end.
The ideal pattern would match patterns like 'word, wo'rd, word', wo''''rd word, but should not match ' by itself.
It would also be nice if the pattern could match multiple specified characters, so if I also wanted to match ? along with the aforementioned ' it could match strings like 'wor''??d but never solely ? or '.

It is \b'|'\b

Did it work as expected? Could you please provide test cases if it is not what you seek?

I am too lazy to create test cases. @WiktorStribiżew

OK, then use Cary's solution.

I assume you wish to match
'word, wo'rd, word', word, shouldn't've and hadn't've'
but not
', wo''d, ''wod, wod'', ^cat or dog&.
In that case one could match
(?<!\S)(?![a-z']*'')[a-z']*[a-z][a-z']*(?!\S)

Demo
I have expressed the regex at the demo in extended mode to improve readability. That triggers a pre-processing step that strips out comments and whitespaces before the expression is parsed.

Notes:
(?<!\S)

(same as (?<=^|\s)) is a negative lookbehind that asserts that the current match is not preceded by a character other than a whitespace.
(?![a-z']*'')

is a negative lookahead that asserts that the current location is not followed by one or more letters or apostrophes followed by two apostrophes in a row.
[a-z']*[a-z][a-z']*

matches a word containing a letter and any number of apostrophes.
(?!\S)

(same as (?=\s|$)) is a negative lookahead that asserts that the current match is not followed by a character other than a whitespace.
